# How to import .anm, .anim or .dae_anim files into Blender?

Tags: animation, import, conversion

Is there a way to import ***.anm***, ***.anim*** or ***.dae_anim*** files into Blender and/or convert them to *armature actions*? 
I've imported the ***.dae*** (collada) rigged model, but it contains only a single armature action.
[image]

Although there are many other animation actions included in downloaded file, which I have no idea how to import to blender.
[image]

Hope somebody has the experience with this and help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can that help ? https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Phabtar/Full_COLLADA_Animation_Support_for_Blender